# Dynamically update transport layer between frontend and backend during local development (vue.js, axios and spring-boot)?

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js

I have a frontend/backend project based on:

https://jaxlondon.com/blog/java-core-languages/put-spring-boot-und-vue-js-practical-use-project-tutorial/

I can develop the UI parts of the frontend with hotload by running:

```
npm install
npm run serve
```

But how do I test my changes in the frontend against a running backend - e.g. If I just want experiment with different calls in the frontend to the backend API?

Right now when I want to build and run the backend I run:

```
mvn clean install
java -jar backend/target/backend-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

which will first build the frontend, copy the frontend files to the backend, build the backend and finally start/run it.

But I don't want to go through that full path each time I want to experiment with different calls to the backend API in the frontend.

I have looked at `spring-boot-devtools` :

https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi01Le6x8LmAhXCDOwKHTrUDmQQFjACegQIAhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.vojtechruzicka.com%2Fspring-boot-devtools%2F&usg=AOvVaw3LfvxbQ-5ZW33tG8gFJjoL

And yes I can start the backend from my eclipse IDE by running the main class but I still need it to either start the frontend separately or somehow update the frontend resources dynamically (when changed) in the running backend.

But I still don't really see how I can hot reload my frontend source into the running backend.

Of course I can separate the frontend and backend so the backend only contains the API (not the frontend resources) and start it independently. But before doing that I would like to see if I can accomplish the above development process using my existing project.

Any suggestions/directions on how to proceed?

Comment: why do you copy front-end files to back-end?

Comment: The frontend files are copied to the spring boot backend since its being hosted in the spring boot server, see https://jaxlondon.com/blog/java-core-languages/put-spring-boot-und-vue-js-practical-use-project-tutorial/ for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done the same on my personal project. I can detail it out for you and see if that helps,

https://github.com/reflexdemon/problem-generateor is a spring boot application mainly written for backend. I have a sub folder inside that as `ui/vue-ui/`, this is mainly having the UI project that is making use of my spring boot application.

I have setup my UI project in such a way that while doing local development I can point to my spring boot app using proxy https://github.com/reflexdemon/problem-generateor/blob/master/ui/vue-ui/vue.config.js.

This setup will get the local development work fine, as a matter of fact, while doing development on my local I have the ability to point to the real service deployed on remote PC to be able to serve for me.

Here are some additional things that are done,

1. Always point all the `/api` to point to backend, so that the proxy config is simple
2. The built package is copied to `src/main/resources/static/` so that while deploying spring boot app this works as a single deployable artifact

You can have both modules work independently.

Answer (score 1):

frontend development has its own ecosystem and the project you're pointing is based on maven which is java build automation tool.

it's really good for release process because maven frontend-maven-plugin allows to run all commands to build final artifact centrally by maven without direct interference of any frontend tools

but for ease of frontend development you can use one of the frontend powerful tools in name of [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) it has got a [dev server](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) plugin that allows you to hot reload your frontend project

this plugin overall functionality is to provide a light weight web server to serve your frontend files like html,css,js and ..

when using dev server you should configure it to use a proxy for redirecting API calls to your spring boot application

```
devServer: {
contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
compress: true,
port: 9000,
proxy: {
    '/api': {
        target: 'http://localhost:8080',
        secure: false
    }
}
```

Restart the webpack dev server and when you visit the code server at http://localhost:9000/api/posts you see the same results as http://localhost:3000/api/posts from the api server.

Comment: Yes I am already using the dev server for hot reload but as I mention I want to hit the API in the spring boot backend I have written and not just serve the frontend with the dev server. Regarding using a proxy to hit my spring boot backend can you provide examples?